# PhpStorm SSH / SFTP cygwin

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, sftp

I want to use my cygwin configuration for SSH ou SFTP connection but doesn't work.

My configucation file "config" is in directory `C:\cygwin64\home\<username>\.ssh.` This configuration file define an SSH proxy jump and send some environment variables. This configuration file work fine in cygwin to connect in SSH or SFTP.

In PhpStorm settings I've specified the shell path in `Tools > Terminal` to be `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i`. All local terminal use cygwin fine. But the ssh connection don't use my configuration file. I tried copying configuration in `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh` directory but that does not work.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to install the latest version of OpenSSH. To achieve this, I did the following actions:

1. Installing the scoop package manager (https://scoop.sh/) using PowerShell

   `$ Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope CurrentUser`  Answer Y

   `$ Invoke-Expression (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://get.scoop.sh')`
2. Installing OpenSSH

   `$ scoop install win32-openssh`

   normally the installation modifies the environment variable %PATH% to add the path something like `C:\Users\<username>\scoop\shims`. Otherwise you have to add it.
3. Modification of the environment variable %PATH% to remove the path `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`
4. Enable the "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" service
   On keyboard press Windows + R

   Type: `services.msc` and press Enter.

   Double click on the "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" service

   Select the "Automatic" start type and start the service.

After these actions, I was able to connect from the Windows cmd terminal. I tested from PhpStorm and it works too.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, creating `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config` file pointing to the actual location of keys (using a valid Windows path) should help. But PhpStorm does not support ProxyJump and ProxyCommand instructions in it because there is no support for it from OpenSSH client's Windows port and we cannot use Cygwin or MinGW OpenSSH clients, which support proxying, but require running in theirs own shell subsystem. Here's a related bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-214679